# Removed Movies folder, now want it back

Tags: macos, finder

That's it. I typed `rm -r ~/Movies` in the Terminal and entered the root password. Now I want to get this nice-looking Movies folder with a corresponding icon back to my home folder.

Folder was completely empty, so there is no need for data recovery, I just want to recreate the original Movies folder.

Thanks in advance!

**UPD**: I've tried `mkdir ~/Movies` but it creates a regular folder.

Comment: Is `mkdir ~/Movies` not enough?

Comment: @patrix Sorry, I should mention that. I tried `mkdir ~/Movies` but resulting folder looks just like any regular folder, and I'm afraid that OS X will not treat it as the special folder.

Comment: So you are missing the icon then? Don't think there is very much else which is different as such.

Comment: @patrix I'm not only missing the icon, but I'm also afraid that OS X might treat the original Music folder in a special way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, OS X doesn't treat 'special' folders like ~/Movies any more special than others - it just doesn't let you delete them via the Finder.

I could upload the Movies folder ICNS file, but if I did, you wouldn't get proper icons for different sizes (see screenshot.)
[image: In case you can't see this image, the real Movies folder has a proper border for smaller icons, however the unoriginal one doesn't.]

I guess a method would be to create a new user account, get the Movies folder from *that* and then copy it to your Home folder.